# java 21 preview unnamed symbol for try-with-resource

Tags: java

I'm reading the java 21 new future [java21 unnamed](https://openjdk.org/jeps/443) ,and I trying to the use unnamed in try-with-resource,But i get the Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class the Resoen is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal field name "" in class,Is it because this function has not been developed yet or is it a preview, so it is unstable? Or is there something wrong with my usage?

```java
 try (var _ = new FileInputStream("/Users/task/Desktop/ttt")) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Please tell me the relevant information. Thank you.

Comment: The Java 21 specification says "The underscore may be used in identifiers formed of two or more characters, but it cannot be used as a one-character identifier due to being a keyword.". This may be the cause of the error.

Comment: In my case the problem was with `_` usage in lambda: `items.forEach(_ -> someAction());`. It was working locally but failing in production

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8313323). According to the bug report, it is fixed in Java 21.0.1.

This only occurs when variable names are generated, such as by using the `-g` option.

You can use `-g:none` to disable it, or turn this option off in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA):

[image]

Rebuild the project and it should run.