# Can't run test JUnit 5 with Java 21 preview syntax with Maven and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, junit5

I try to run a simple test in JUnit 5 which contains anonymous variable `_`.

I can compile with no problem, but I can't execute the test. I have this error:

```
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Illegal field name "" in class com/model/ConfTest
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Illegal field name "" in com/model/ConfTest
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:628)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:285)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:250)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1203)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1055)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:871)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

Here the Maven configuration

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>21</release>
          <compilerArgs><arg>--enable-preview</arg></compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

example of code:

```java
@Test
void test_with_(){
    val l = List.of("a", "b", "c");
    val l2 = l.stream().map(_ -> "not work");
}
```

If I replace `_` by a variable name like `aVariable`, I can execute test with success.

Any idea on how to use preview syntax of Java 21 in test?

[EDIT]

The entire pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <vavr.version>0.10.4</vavr.version>
    <vertx-core.version>4.4.5</vertx-core.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>
    <commons-validator.version>1.7</commons-validator.version>
    <java.version>21</java.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.30</lombok.version>
    <assertj-vavr.version>0.4.3</assertj-vavr.version>
    <awaitility.version>4.2.0</awaitility.version>
    <mockito-junit-jupiter.version>5.3.1</mockito-junit-jupiter.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.10.0</junit-jupiter.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
        <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
        <version>${vavr.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
        <version>${vertx-core.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-validator.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <!-- VULNERABILITY -->
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <!-- TEST -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-vavr</artifactId>
        <version>${assertj-vavr.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
        <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
        <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito-junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- TEST -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-vavr</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
      <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>${java.version}</release>
          <compilerArgs><arg>--enable-preview</arg></compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please show your full pom file... and there seemed to be things which are not correct because here: https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2023/06/2023-06-24-how-to-use-jdk21-preview-features-incubator/ the setup works...

Comment: I just posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77256384/5133585) about this hours ago :)

Comment: I would recheck the JEP's because it looks like the "_" pattern does not work (yet) for streams... For switch etc. it works.

Comment: @Sweeper I was just going to pass the same link.

Comment: try removing space after underscore(_)

Comment: @khmarbaise The stream isn't the important part. The important part is the lambda expression, and [JEP 443: Unnamed Patterns and Variables (Preview)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/443) claims that "_an unnamed variable (denoted by an underscore)_" can be used as a "_formal parameter of a lambda expression (JLS 15.27.1)_". Though from Sweeper's link, perhaps there's a bug involved.

Comment: I remove the space after _ but it doesn't work. The answer of Sweeper works. I must deactivate generating debug info. I try your code khmarbaise, it runs. But if I add my test in your project I have the same error. So if I understand I must wait the bug fix https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8313323 ?